# Unable to edit my moderator nomination

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-election

I just nominated myself but I left a sentence incomplete.
I get a 500 error when trying to submit my edits.

The robot is broken

[image: Robot Broke]

Comment: Presumably moderators are expected to be perfect first time, every time ;-)

Comment: Magically it works again. Weird

Comment: else leave it as is, it's good enough already